# Openfire server stop automatically in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: java, android, hibernate, ubuntu-14.04, openfire

My Openfire server stopped automatically. it happens every 2 or 3 days. I have to restart service manually what could be the issue? it really a big issue and my application are live.Please suggest me what was the issue and how I can be fixed it.
Error log:

2017.08.23 09:37:35 org.jivesoftware.openfire.plugin.rest.exceptions.RESTExceptionMapper - UserAlreadyExistsException: Could not create new user with ressource 3 
atg.jivesoftware.openfire.container.PluginManager.loadPlugin(PluginManager.javaorg.jivesoftware.openfire.container.PluginMonitor$MonitorTask$4.call(PluginMonitor.javaorg.jivesoftware.openfire.container.PluginMonitor$MonitorTask$4.call(PluginMonitor.javaat java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java
at java.lang.Thread.run

Comment: These logs are not enough to identify the root cause, have you checked all log files? Is there any indication of Out Of Memory? Because a major reason can be Out of Memory but it will be printed in logs.

Comment: Yes, you are right.Its happing due to Out Of Memory.Thanks for your suggestion. :)